# Perl require fails to find Library in @INC when used in eval

Tags: perl

depending on if a certain Module can be loaded, I'd like to decide if it is used:

```
BEGIN {
  eval {
    require "Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5";
    $hdf5 = "Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5";
  };
  if ($@) {
    require "Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5_mockup";
    $hdf5 = "Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5_mockup";
  }
}
```

which results in 
 
`Can't locate Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5_mockup in @INC`

However:

```
use Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5; 
use Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5_mockup;
```

works fine. Also when I switch HDF5 and HDF5_mockup in the BEGIN block, it locates always the one I require first, and fails to find the second one.
Thanks for any pointer.

Comment: does it work if you use bareword module name: `require Bio::EnsEMBL::HDFS;` and `require Bio::EnsEMBL::HDFS_mockup`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because when you quote the module when using [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), it uses the quoted string as the name of the actual module file. So instead of looking for `Bio/EnsEMBL/HDF5.pm`, it's searching `@INC` for a file named `Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5`.

Remove the quotes so that the module name is a bareword. Here's an example:

Notice how the module name hasn't been transformed into a file path:

```
require "Data::Dumper";
Can't locate Data::Dumper in @INC (@INC contains: ...
```

Now, in this example, I've intentionally mistyped the module name so I could produce the error. Notice how the module has been transformed into an actual file path:

```
require Data::Dumperx;
Can't locate Data/Dumperx.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Dumperx module)
```

Comment: Ouch. Not seeing that was a sure sign to stop coding and start the weekend. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
use Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5;
```

almost identical to

```
BEGIN {
   require Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5; 
   import Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5; 
}
```

and

```
# Looks for file "Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5_mockup"
require "Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5_mockup";
```

isn't equivalent to

```
# Looks for file "Bio/EnsEMBL/HDF5_mockup.pm"
require Bio::EnsEMBL::HDF5_mockup;
```